# Grep-ing a list of filename against a csv list of names

Tags: shell, unix, csv, awk

I have a CSV files containing a list of ids, numbers, each on a row. Let's call that file ids.csv
In a directory i have a big number of files, name "file_123456_smth.csv", where 123456 is an id that could be found in the ids csv file
Now, what I am trying to achieve: compare the names of the files with the ids stored in ids.csv. If 123456 is found in ids.csv then the filename should be displayed.
What i've tried:

```
ls -a | xargs grep -L cat ../../ids.csv
```

Of course, this does not work, but gives an idea of my direction.

Comment: I don't know why Python is tagged, but if you do not want a quadratic solution, you can use a set or dict.

Comment: @user189 Python was automatically suggested by SO and didn't noticed it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see if I understood you correctly...

```
$ cat ids.csv 
123
456
789

$ ls *.csv
file_123_smth.csv  file_321_smth.csv  file_789_smth.csv  ids.csv

$ ./c.sh 
123 found in file_123_smth.csv
789 found in file_789_smth.csv
```

where c.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID="ids.csv"

for file in *.csv
do
    if [[ $file =~ file ]]    # just do the filtering on files
    then                      # containing the actual string "file"
        id=$(cut -d_ -f2 <<< "$file")
        grep -q "$id" $ID && echo "$id found in $file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: the example works great, but when i try to update it to real life filenames it does not - the real filenames are like so: Offerfeed_9901223_en.full.csv. How should i addapt the cut to match this ? thanks!

Comment: Also, could you please explain what should the if [[ $file =~ file ]] do ?

Comment: Glad you liked it! The operator `=~` is bash regexp match. I use it to see if the string "file" is present in the filename. The reason for it is to only do the parsing on on the correct filenames and not on `ids.csv` since I use globbing `*.csv` to list all files to be parsed.

Comment: Regarding you first comment. Change `file` into `Offerfeed`. See my explanation on why in my previous comment